# MySQL counting the returned count of a result set

Tags: mysql, sql

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (member), count( UID ) AS numUID
FROM memberdata
GROUP BY Member
ORDER BY count( UID ) DESC
```

What I get back, looks a lot like this:

```
A name 1    175
A name 2    38
A name 3    37
A name 4    36
A name 5    36
```

What I want to do now is get the count of numUID, in the above example I may get a result like:

```
**numUID**   **COUNT**
   175           1
   38            1
   37            1
   36            2
```

I've searched far and wide, but I can't seem to get the information I need to put this query together properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a subselect and another GROUP BY:

```
SELECT numUID, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT member, count(UID) AS numUID
    FROM memberdata
    GROUP BY Member
) T1
GROUP BY numUID
```

I should also warn you that you are also misusing `DISTINCT`. When you use `DISTINCT` it always looks at the entire row. Writing `DISTINCT(x) , y` is exactly the same as `DISTINCT x, y`. When you use `GROUP BY` it is guaranteed that you will only get one row per group. There is no need to use `DISTINCT` here.